# xterm not displaying color when echoing a coloured string

Tags: colors, xterm, escape-characters

In an `Xterm(271)` (under Ubuntu 12.04) this Octave [script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cprintf-m/) does not print coloured strings (e.g. `cprintf("red","%s\n","test")`, in an executable Octave script). It works fine in a `Xterm(297)` on a different system (Ubuntu 14.04). I fail to see what is the right parameter/value combination to make it work (many relate to color and one to scape sequences, which `cprintf` is using), and can't find a way to figure out how is the `Xterm(297)` configured.

Answer (score 0):

xterm will print colors with the normal system configuration which sets this resource:

```
*customization: -color
```

The problem could be the version of *octave* on the older Ubuntu system rather than configuration or version of *xterm*.  Ubuntu 14.04 would have [octave 3.81](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave/3.8.1-1ubuntu1), while 12.04 may have [octave 3.2](https://launchpad.net/~dr-graef/+archive/ubuntu/octave-3.6.precise) (unless you have the backport of 3.6).

The [cprintf script](https://sourceforge.net/p/cprintf-m/code/ci/default/tree/cprintf.m) generates calls to `printf`, e.g.,

```
printf("\033[1;31mtest\n")
```

According to the [current octave documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Escape-Sequences-in-String-Constants.html#index-escape-sequence-notation), that should work; the release notes for [3.8](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.8.html), [3.6](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.6.html), [3.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.4.html) do not mention escape or printf in this regard.  But if your xterm resources are correct, then a bug in octave is the place to look.

Comment: Thanks for drifting my attention towards Octave, I was stacked on xterm configuring. Currently it's 3.2 version running, will check this out.

Comment: Out-of-the-box, Ubuntu would setup xterm so it colors; the `customization` resource is an occasional problem.